# Doesn't see my path in urls.py, page not found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I go to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/personalities/?fio=ti" and see "Page not found". And the same page shows this path:

```
api/v1/ personalities/ (?P<fio>.+)/$
```

Why doesn't it work?

my main `urls.py`:

```
path('personalities/', include('api.v1.personalities.urls'))
```

`personalities.urls.py`:

```
re_path('(?P<fio>.+)/$', PersonalitiesFilterView.as_view())
```

I followed the documentation from the django_filters website
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: The part after the `?` is the *querystring*, and not part of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part after the `?` is the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), and not part of the path. You thus can not capture this with a regex, or `path(…)`.

You can read the querystring as a dictionary-like structure with the [**`request.query_params`** [DRF-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params) (only for `APIView`s) or [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET).

The pattern thus looks like:

```
path('', PersonalitiesFilterView.as_view())
```

and in the view, you thus can access the value for `fio` with:

```
class PersonalitiesFilterView(ListAPIView):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'fio' in self.request.query_params:
            value = self.request.query_params['fio']
            # do something …
        # …
```